# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I initially tried using python to run but there were different errors so I tried using python3 and received the error in the title. I am trying to connect to server and download a file that has tls implemented.

```py
import socket, ssl, pprint
import os, time
import threading

def main():
    s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s2,
                           server_side = False,
                           ca_certs="CA.crt",
                           cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)
    s2.connect(('localhost',10024))
    filename = raw_input("What file do you wish to download? -> ")

    if filename != 'q':
        s2.send(filename)

        data = s2.recv(1024)
        if data [:7] == 'fEXISTS':
            fSize = long(data[7:])

            message = raw_input("The file you wish to download is " +str(fSize)+\
                        "bytes, would you like to proceed? (y/n): ")

            if message == 'y':
                s2.send ('OK')
                f = open('new_'+filename, 'wb')
                data = s2.recv(2000000)
                totalRecv = len(data)
                f.write(data)

                while totalRecv < fSize:
                    data = s2.recv(2000000)
                    totalRecv += len(data)
                    f.write(data)
                    progress = ((totalRecv/float(fSize))*100)
                    print ("{0: .2F}".format(progress)+\
                            "% Completed")
        else:
            print ("ERROR: File does not exist!")
    s2.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you share which line you received the error on?

Comment: it says line 17, the bit where s2.connect is

Comment: Why are you using Python 2? The above code can't run with Python 3 as well, since it uses `raw_input()`. BTW: Per site guidelines, you need to provide a [mcve], so in particular if the code after the error isn't executed anyway, you should remove it. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

After wrapping the socket in an SSL context (with `ssl.wrap_socket`), you should not be using the original socket anymore.

You should be calling `connect`, `send`, `recv`, etc. on `ssl_sock`, not on `s2`.

(Specifically, when you call `ssl.wrap_socket`, the `.detach` method is called on the original socket which removes the file descriptor from it. The file descriptor is transferred to the SSL socket instance. The only thing you can do with the original then is close/destroy it.)

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I tried changing the s2 to ssl_sock but received a different error instead. "socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer"

Comment: Calling `connect` on the wrapped socket should cause an SSL handshake to occur with the server. There are many things that can go wrong in and following that step. You need to post many more details in order for anyone to be able to help you. I would first try starting from one of the examples in the python `ssl` module documentation page. For example, connect to python.org port 443 and verify you can do the handshake, retrieve the peer certificate and send and receive data. If that works, then switch back to your local scenario, look for logs on the server for details about what went wrong.